# MuleSoft runtime property

Tags: variables, runtime, mulesoft, tanuki

The current version of mule runtime we are using is 4.3.0. We have multiple environments where we have to set up the runtimes.

We want to define a variable in the runtime wrapper.conf and use that variable across multiple properties.

Tried to follow the tanukui software instructions "https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/props-envvars.html"

set.default.ENV_BASE_PATH=/path/to/the/environment
wrapper.java.additional.22=-DMULE_LOG_DOMAIN_V2=%**ENV_BASE_PATH**%/logs/%***WRAPPER_HOSTNAME***%/DomainV2

WRAPPER_HOSTNAME is working which is a default variable that tanuki provides. But the custom variable "ENV_BASE_PATH" is not working.

when the runtime is comes up it is not taking "ENV_BASE_PATH" as a variable but taking it as an absolute value.

Comment: What is the operating system? Is mule running as a service?

Comment: OS is RHEL and yes Mule is running as a service.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to just avoid using environment variables in the wrapper. Just replace it by the actual value. It doesn't look as good but it will work.

Comment: Thank you!!. Actual Value does work but looking for a variable approach as it is easy to maintain across multiple environments.

Comment: I understand the intention but environment variables may have limitations depending on the service configuration.  Tanuki docs mention one such scenario for windows. It might depend on your OS service configuration.